# error when playing sine wave via pygame.sndarray

Tags: python, audio, numpy, pygame

I am currently tying to write a little application to manipulate sounds.
The main goal is that I connect a PS3 Controller to a Raspberry Pi and can play and modify sounds via the Analog sticks. That just as a preview why I want to do the following.

I wrote the following Code to create a sine wave and write it into a numpy array.

```
import math, numpy
import pygame

pygame.init()
#>>> (6, 0)

SAMPLERATE = 44100

def tone(freq=1000,volume=16000,length=1):
    num_steps = length*SAMPLERATE
    s = []
    for n in range(num_steps):
        value = int(math.sin(n * freq * (6.28318/SAMPLERATE) * length)*volume)
        s.append( [value,value] )
    x_arr = numpy.array(s)
    return x_arr

pygame.sndarray.make_sound(tone())
```

If I now want to run it I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 19, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygame/sndarray.py", line 131, in make_sound
    return numpysnd.make_sound (array)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygame/_numpysndarray.py", line 75, in make_sound
    return mixer.Sound (array=array)
ValueError: Unsupported integer size 8
```

But I do not really understand where the mistake is.

Comment: To answer this question requires going through a lot more code than needed to reproduce the problem. This makes it hard to give good answers without spending disproportionate amounts of time on the question; most people will rather move on to another question. If you distil the question down to the smallest possible sample that reproduces the problem the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well. The edited question does not have to do the same thing as the whole of the code, it only needs to reproduce the one aspect that you need help with.

Comment: Note that all you need to reproduce this are imports and `pygame.init(); wave = numpy.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]); pygame.sndarray.make_sound(wave)`.

Comment: Okay thanks for the hint
But my question was in second place referred to the whole task if it would be possible to complete the task with my current attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.sndarray.make_sound` seems to only support certain integer types, like `int8`:

```
import numpy
import pygame

pygame.init()
#>>> (6, 0)

wave = numpy.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]], dtype="int64") # default
pygame.sndarray.make_sound(wave)
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   File "", line 8, in <module>
#>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygame/sndarray.py", line 131, in make_sound
#>>>     return numpysnd.make_sound (array)
#>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygame/_numpysndarray.py", line 75, in make_sound
#>>>     return mixer.Sound (array=array)
#>>> ValueError: Unsupported integer size 8
```

vs

```
wave = numpy.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]], dtype="int8")
pygame.sndarray.make_sound(wave)
#>>> <Sound object at 0x7f6adfd395d0>
```

Note that the maximum integer an `int8` can store is a measly 127.

Comment: Okay do you have another spontaneous attempt to solve this? For A Sample rate of 44100 127 is a little less.

Comment: @hGen This only means that each item can only hold a number up to 127, not that you can't have a lot of samples at whatever sample rate you want. Note the 127 is just the arbitrary "maximum volume", and -128 is just the the arbitrary "minimum volume".

Comment: As `sin` always is from -1 to 1, all you need to do is set the volume less than 127.

Comment: Okay it works thanks. do you know how I can play the sound as long as I press the assigned button without interfering the tone after and after?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Comments aren't a nice place to ask questions.